# Что требуется для создания пользовательских пресетов цвета? - React Native

Tags: reactjs, функции, react-native, react-hook, передача-данных

Пытаюсь написать такое приложение на React Native, подскажите, что требуется (и как это применять?) для создания пресетов для цвета. То есть, у меня есть Color Wheel - модуль (как отдельная функция) и ScrollView-компонент с каким-то количеством TouchableOpacity (пресетов) внутри.
Задача:

1. При нажатии на один из пресетов - цвет, который хранит в себе пресет, применялся на внешнее колесо (индикатор)
2. При зажатии пресета - цвет пресета обновлялся на тот, что выбран на Color Wheel в данный момент

Также непонятно, как оптимизировать это. Сильно падает fps при взаимодействии с Color Wheel, если он не лежит в отдельной функции. Так же и со слайдером.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот по-максимуму сокращенный код:

```jsx
//Все нужные imports

function Presets() {
    function SliderValue() {
        const [valueBR, setValueBR] = useState(100)
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.sliderValue}>
                    <Slider
                        value={valueBR}
                        onValueChange={(value) => {
                            setValueBR(value);
                            console.log('Slider Value:', value);
                            Keyboard.dismiss;
                        }}
                        anyProps // И другие параметры
                    />
                </View>
                    <View>
                        <View style={styles.ValueStrokeButton}>
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.ValueStrokeButtonText} // Это то, что 88 на скрине (значение слайдера)
                            value={valueBR}
                            onChangeText={setValueBR}
                            anyProps // И другие параметры
                            ></TextInput>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    function ColorWheelComponent() {
        const [quantityHSV, setQuantityHSV] = useState('#ffffff')
        const onColorChange = (color) => {
            setQuantityHSV(color);
            console.log('ColorWheel Color:', quantityHSV);
        }
        const onColorComplete = (color) => {
            console.log('ColorWheel Color (Complete):', color);
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.ellipseStack}>
                    <Svg viewBox="0 0 325 325" style={styles.ellipse}> 
                        <Ellipse 
                            stroke={'ТУТ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ЦВЕТ'} // Это сам индикатор
                            anyProps // И другие параметры
                        ></Ellipse>
                    </Svg>
                    <View>
                        <ColorWheel
                            initialColor={'#ffffff'}
                            onColorChange={onColorChange}
                            onColorChangeComplete={onColorComplete}
                            style={styles.colorwheel}
                            anyProps // И другие параметры
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.Indicators}>
                    <View style={styles.hsvStrokeButton}> 
                        <TextInput
                        style={styles.hsvStrokeButtonText} // Это #ff78c3 со скрина
                        anyProps // И другие параметры
                        ></TextInput>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <View style={styles.lineButtom}></View>
        <View style={styles.lineTop}></View>
        <View style={styles.RgbHsvSlider}>
            <Text style={styles.rgbButton} onPress={() => console.log('RGB')}>RGB</Text>
            <SliderValue style={styles.SliderValueInPanel}/>
            <Text style={styles.hsvButton} onPress={() => console.log('HSV')}>HSV</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.PresetsScrollArea}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={styles.PresetsStackScroll}>
                <View style={styles.PresetsStack}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 1')} style={presets.p1}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 2')} style={presets.p2}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 3')} style={presets.p3}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 4')} style={presets.p4}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 5')} style={presets.p5}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 6')} style={presets.p6}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 7')} style={presets.p7}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 8')} style={presets.p8}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 9')} style={presets.p9}></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('preset 10')} style={presets.p10}></TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View>
            <ColorWheelComponent/>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Presets;
```

Comment: Я точно знаю что fps падает из за того что очень много цветов на твоем Color Wheel, ведь ты перемещаешь ползунок по тысячи цветов сразу, и еще к тому же идет обработка цвета пиксела чтобы передать его значение... Вспомним что такое RGB - red, green, blue НО каждый цвет представлен 256 оттенками, то есть 256*256*256 = 16,7 миллионов цветов на твоей палитре

Comment: @Tikhon, да, понимаю + когда я изменяю цвет, обновляется все, что в той же функции. Поэтому и принял решение разделить по функциям, но не могу решить из-за этого проблему с пресетами)